# issue when calling map in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using jupyter notebook. This line used to work perfectly, but now, when I run it

```
#labels is a numpy array
new_labels = list(map(lambda x: 0 if x < 1 else 1, labels))
```

I get

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Looks like either `map` or `list` is somehow a `dict` object. Do you have a variable called `list` or `map` in your code? If so, it will shadow the builtin

Comment: Restart and clear output and c if d error persists

Comment: @ForceBru exact - that was it !

Comment: @sammywemmy that's what I did and it works now - thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use np.[where](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this and easily transfer to new_labels. Assuming that you want to transform the values which are less than 0 to 0.

> syntax
>
> *numpy.where(condition[, x, y])*

```
In [3]: arr=np.array([1,-1,2,-2,3,-3])


In [4]: np.where(arr<0,0,1)
Out[4]: array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

**On second thought**,your code worked for me.Below is the code .

```
In [16]: arr=np.array([1,-1,2,-2,3,-3])

In [17]: list(map(lambda x : 0 if x<0 else 1, arr))
Out[17]: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what ForceBru and tedd said, you could also use a Boolean expression directly:

```py
import numpy as np

labels = np.array([0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, -1, 2])

new_labels = labels >= 1
new_labels
```

array([False, False,  True,  True, False,  True])

```py
# or, if it has to be a list of integers:
new_labels = [int(item) for item in (labels >= 1)]
new_labels
```

[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

Answer (score 0):

I had a variable `list` (I am pretty new to `python`) and it induced some conflicts. I cleaned the code and restarted the kernel and it works.